# How to make a "matrix" for puzzle bubble?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Hey guys, I'm trying to make a puzzle bubble clone but I'm stumped on how to handle the background stuff. Mostly with the fact that the lines don't match up (i.e: instead of a bubble having another no top of it, one on the upper-left and one on the upper-right, it has one on the upper left and one on the upper right http://dl.dropbox.com/u/680263/puzzle_bobble_2.jpg) and how to determine which bubbles pop when I make shot (and which fall) without making a brute-force algorithm that would make my i7 cry.

Can anyone give some sugestions on how to handle this?

Comment: If you don't get any joy here, try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For those of us who don't know Puzzle Bubble you should describe the "which bubbles pop" rules.  You won't be able to write an algorithm to do it until you can clearly describe the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a multi-dimensional array? How about a "bubble" structure like this:

```
typedef struct t_bubble_tag {
   t_colour colour; /* whatever else you want to store about your bubble */
   struct t_bubble_tag pUpperLeft;
   struct t_bubble_tag pUpperRight;
   struct t_bubble_tag pLeft;
   struct t_bubble_tag pRight;
   struct t_bubble_tag pLowerLeft;
   struct t_bubble_tag pLowerRight;
} t_bubble;
```

Then when you pop a given bubble, you can do a tree traverse down both ways and sideways both ways, and get rid of any "island" of bubbles that are not eventually attached to the top wall. Bear in mind bubbles can be supported by "arms" of other bubbles from the side or below.

I suspect that this is less storage efficient, but more speed efficient, than using a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Then we're talking about a simple array, I guess But shouldn't the bubble neighbours be pointers to other bubbles instead the implementation you have posted? Maybe, I'm not getting the whole idea. Anyway, I think that your implementation is the best workaround.

Comment: @renatorodrigues: Yes, I definitely meant pointers, well spotted!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this Puzzle Bubble game in Lua with tables, 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD0fQVSj_7w&list=UUlKVS4jFzSMXF9l6Jw1uoaw&feature=plcp
you can see the code here:
https://gist.github.com/1725481

You can use this implementation for the puzzle board using a bidimensional table:

```
function Puzzle:loadPuzzle()
    print("Loading level "..level)
    self.state     = PUZZLE_LOADING
    -- create the bubbles
    local n = 0
    local k = 0
    local w = self.width
    local h = self.height
    for i=1, h do
     self.bubbles[i] = {}
     n = 0
     if levels[level][i]~=nil then
         n = #(levels[level][i])
     end
     local aux = 0
     if math.fmod(i,2)==0 then
        aux = (self.bubbleSize/2) + 16
     end
     local y = self.initHeight+self.tileSize*self.height - self.bubbleSize - (i-1)*self.tileSize
     for j=1,self.width do
        local c,state = nil,BUBBLE_EMPTY
        if nil==levels[level][i] or nil == levels[level][i][j] then 
            c = nil
            if aux>0 and j==self.width then
                state = nil
            end
        else
            c = levels[level][i][j]
            state = BUBBLE_ATTACHED
            self:addCurrentColor(c,currentColors)
        end
        self.bubbles[i][j] = Bubble(
            vec2(aux+self.initWidth+self.tileSize*j - self.bubbleSize,y),
            self.tileSize, -- bubble radius size
            c --color
         ) 
        self.bubbles[i][j].state = state 
      end 
    end
    sound(SOUND_POWERUP, 33755)
    self.state     = PUZZLE_PLAYING
    print(""..(#currentColors).." colors")
end
```

and write in C code is simple...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using this data-structure in a puzzle bubble game is a good idea, because it needs to update a lot of pointers for all the bubbles in the board.

Just take this simple case:

- when you have two or three bubbles of the same colour and 2 with different colors, all already set in the board; and the next bubble launched is of the first color, it hits the group of three, you have first to attach the bubble in its place and then update all the pointers.
- then, you have to go through all these pointers searching for bubble sisters (same colour and adjacents) but with this datastructure is much harder to find because you have to build several recursive functions with a lot of conditions.

Also you have to know that the first line of bubbles have more than the next, it is, even rows have 7 (for example) and odd rows have 6 bubbles.

With a table you have to consider these cases, there is also a complexity here.
Maybe, another implementation could be to use a tree where the root has the first line of bubbles as child nodes.